# Android with Scrollview for half screen only

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

Rite now, the entire screen is scrollable.

[image]

I would like to set the Part B (refer photo) only scrollable meanwhile the Part A (video part)
is fixed. Below is my code rite now. Please help.

```
<LinearLayout --some code here-->
    <ScrollView
        --some code here-->
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/videoPlayer"
                >
            <VideoView
                   --some code here--/>
            <MediaController
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    />
            <TextView
                    --some code />
            <TextView
                    --some code />
            <ImageView some code
                </ImageView>
            <RelativeLayout --some code here-->

                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/scarfPrice"
                        />
                <Button android:id="@+id/btnPurchase"
                        />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <LinearLayout --some code 
        --some code here-->
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/videoPlayer"
                >
            <VideoView
                   --some code here--/>
            <MediaController
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    />
            <ScrollView>
                <LinearLayout>
                    <TextView
                            --some code />
                    <TextView
                            --some code />
                    <ImageView some code
                        </ImageView>
                    <RelativeLayout --some code here-->

                        <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/scarfPrice"
                                />
                        <Button android:id="@+id/btnPurchase"
                                />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

tldr: Only wrap the content part in the scrollview but since a scrollview can only have one child, nest another linearlayout inside of the scrollview.

EDIT: Remove original `</ScrollView>` and redundant `LinearLayout`

```
 <LinearLayout --some code 
        --some code here-->
            >
        <VideoView
               android:id="@+id/videoPlayer"
               --some code here--/>
        <MediaController
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                />
        <ScrollView>
            <LinearLayout>
                <TextView
                        --some code />
                <TextView
                        --some code />
                <ImageView some code
                    </ImageView>
                <RelativeLayout --some code here-->

                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/scarfPrice"
                            />
                    <Button android:id="@+id/btnPurchase"
                            />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="2">
        <!-- Part A -->
   </LinearLayout>
   <ScrollView android:layout_weight="3">
       <LinearLayout>
           <!-- Part B -->
       </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Part A would take up 2/5 of the screen.
Part B would take up 3/5 of the screen and only Part B would be scrollable.